# Azure Worker Role: SynchronizationContext.Current is null at first but then changes to class of type System.Threading.SynchronizationContext

Tags: azure, async-await, azure-worker-roles

I have some code that looks like this:

```
if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
{
    var task = fooAsync();
    task.Wait();
}
```

I know that Wait() blocks the current thread so it should only be used in Console/Windows Service applications. I thought that in console/windows service SynchronizationContext.Current was always null.

I use this code in Azure Worker Role and at first it executed fine. SynchronizationContext.Current is null.  But at some point it stopped executing.

When I checked the log, SynchronizationContext.Current changed from null to an object of type "System.Threading.SynchronizationContext" and stayed that way.

Microsoft has an article about SynchronizationContext:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx

They say when Current is null, it will use System.Threading.SynchronizationContext by default, but it is weird why it stays null for a while but then starts returning initilized System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.

So why is SynchronizationContext.Current null at first, but then changes to object of type "System.Threading.SynchronizationContext"?  Does it point to some memory leak or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Here's another interesting article on SyncContext and TaskScheduler: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/
Note that for Azure cloud services, `TaskScheduler.Default` is `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`